# tricky number system question

Tags: number-theory

Hello i got this question on my aptitude exam.I tried dividing both side by 5.But was unable to get the answer

if(60-a)(60-b)(60-c)(60-d)(60-e)=1025 what is the value of a+b+c+d=?
hint: 1025 is divisible by 5

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Have you stated the problem correctly? Were you actually asked for the sum of a, b, c, d and e?

Answer (score 2):

```
eqn = (60 - a) (60 - b) (60 - c) (60 - d) (60 - e) == 1025;
```

Assuming that all variables are restricted to positive integers

```
solns = FindInstance[{eqn,
   a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0, e > 0},
  {a, b, c, d, e}, Integers, 3]

(*  {{a -> 59, b -> 61, c -> 59, d -> 59, e -> 1085}, 
     {a -> 61, b -> 59, c -> 59, d -> 19, e -> 85}, 
     {a -> 61, b -> 59, c -> 59, d -> 59, e -> 1085}}  *)
```

Verifying that `solns` satisfy `eqn`

```
eqn /. solns

(*  {True, True, True}  *)
```

From the symmetry, there are other obvious additional solutions.

The requested sums are

```
(a + b + c + d) /. solns

(*  {238, 198, 238}  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you factor $1025=5^2\cdot 41$ and assume that the variables need to be positive integers less than $60$, you can either have the factors be $1,1,5,5,41$ or $1,1,1,25,41$.  That leads to variables $59,59,55,55,19$ or $59,59,59,35,19$.  If you were asked for the sum of four of them, you have several answers.  If you were asked for the sum of all five, it is either $247$ or $231$.  If you allow the variables to exceed $60$, you need an even number of the factors to be negative, but the possibilities expand a bunch.  Please make sure you have the correct problem, or punch the poser in the nose if this is the way it was asked.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you give is

```
eqn = (60 - a) (60 - b) (60 - c) (60 - d) (60 - e) == 1025;
```

I have assumed the additional constraints that the variables are non-negative and less than 60.  In addition, I specify an ordering to avoid solutions that are trivial rearrangements.

```
solns = FindInstance[{eqn, 60 > a >= b >= c >= d >= e >= 0}, {a, b, c,
    d, e}, Integers, 3]
(* {{a -> 59, b -> 59, c -> 55, d -> 55, e -> 19}, {a -> 59, b -> 59, 
  c -> 59, d -> 35, e -> 19}} *)

eqn /. solns
(* {True, True} *)
```

It appears that there are two solutions for the sum.  Note that I've assumed that we should consider the sum of all five variables, to avoid different answers arising from trivial permutations.

```
a + b + c + d + e /. solns
(* {247, 231} *)
```

*EDIT*

This answer was written before the question was migrated from the Mathematica site.